# How to add another result of query that result i made to a result (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a problem with this
This would be simple to you but I couldn't find out how to fix my code because of my bad English :((

Here is the query I made

```
SELECT  
  ESCC,
  count(if(DRC =156, DRC,NULL)) AS 'A',
  count(if(DRC =159, DRC,NULL)) AS 'B',
  count(if(DRC =160, DRC,NULL)) AS 'C'
FROM diag_results WHERE diagOrder=1 GROUP BY ESCC;
```

The query above produces the following result.

```
+------+----+----+----+
| ESCC | A  | B  | C  |
+------+----+----+----+
|    1 | 32 | 21 | 92 |
+------+----+----+----+
|    2 | 21 | 33 | 52 |
+------+----+----+----+
...
```

But I'd like to add another result of bellow query to that above result as columns

```
SELECT  
  count(if(DRC =156, DRC,NULL)) AS 'D',
  count(if(DRC =159, DRC,NULL)) AS 'E',
  count(if(DRC =160, DRC,NULL)) AS 'F'
FROM diag_results WHERE diagOrder=2 GROUP BY ESCC;
```

as a result of that

```
+----+----+----+
| D  | E  | F  |
+----+----+----+
| 32 | 21 | 92 |
+----+----+----+
| 21 | 33 | 52 |
+----+----+----+
...
```

So I want to get a result like this

```
+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ESCC | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  |
+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    1 | 32 | 21 | 92 | 32 | 21 | 92 |
+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    2 | 21 | 33 | 52 | 21 | 33 | 52 |
+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

please answer me

Comment: do you want different ids for `diagOrder` ?

Comment: if there are no records, do you want NULL or 0?

Comment: @ysth ahh I should better switch null to 0. Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `count(if())` to do what you want.  It is much simpler to use `sum()` as in:

```
SELECT ESCC,
       sum(diagOrder = 1 and DRC = 156) AS A,
       sum(diagOrder = 1 and DRC = 159) AS B,
       sum(diagOrder = 1 and DRC = 160) AS C,
       sum(diagOrder = 2 and DRC = 156) AS D,
       sum(diagOrder = 2 and DRC = 159) AS E,
       sum(diagOrder = 2 and DRC = 160) AS F
FROM diag_results
WHERE diagOrder IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY ESCC;
```

I also strongly dissuade you from using single quotes for column aliases.  Use single quotes *only* for string and date/time constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  ESCC,
  count(if(diagOrder = 1 AND DRC =156, DRC,NULL)) AS 'A',
  count(if(diagOrder = 1 AND DRC =159, DRC,NULL)) AS 'B',
  count(if(diagOrder = 1 AND DRC =160, DRC,NULL)) AS 'C',
  count(if(diagOrder = 2 AND DRC =156, DRC,NULL)) AS 'D',
  count(if(diagOrder = 2 AND DRC =159, DRC,NULL)) AS 'E',
  count(if(diagOrder = 2 AND DRC =160, DRC,NULL)) AS 'F'
FROM diag_results WHERE diagOrder IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY ESCC;
```